# generic-mode in Emacs single quote strings being highlighted

Tags: emacs

Simple question, I am using generic-mode in Emacs for color coding.  The following works great except that in this language `"` and `'` can be used to denote strings as in `'this is a string'` or `"this is a string"`.  By default in generic-mode, **"hightlighted"** but 'is not'.

```
(require 'generic-x)

 (define-generic-mode
      'foo-mode                         ;; name of the mode to create
      '("#")                           ;; comments start with '!!'
      '("for" "if" "else"  )                     ;; some keywords
      '(("=" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
        ("+" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
        ("-" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
        ("'" . 'font-lock-builtin)     ;; '=' is an operator
        ("<-" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
        ("*" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
        ("/" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
        ("," . 'font-lock-builtin)     ;; ';' is a built-in
        (";" . 'font-lock-builtin))     ;; ';' is a built-in
      '("\\.myext$")                      ;; files for which to activate this mode
       nil                              ;; other functions to call
      "A generic mode for myext files"            ;; doc string for this mode
    )
```

Is there a simple way to make the above treat 's as "s?

Comment: FWIW, I recommend to stay away from `define-generic-mode` and use `define-derived-mode instead (look for "sample-mode.el" to see how that can work): it's a bit harder at first, but it always pays off in the end, because define-generic-mode is very limited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably better follow Stefans advice and use `define-derived-mode`, but as this question was the first time I heard of `generic.el`, I got curious and had to find a way.

In my tests, removing the `font-lock-keyword` entry for `'` and modifying the syntax-table entry for `'` in a function (`'(lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?' "\""))`) in the functions list seems to work.

The complete code I tested:

```
(define-generic-mode
 'foo-mode                         ;; name of the mode to create
  '("#")                           ;; comments start with '!!'
  '("for" "if" "else"  )                     ;; some keywords
  '(("=" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
    ("+" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
    ("-" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
    ("<-" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
    ("*" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
    ("/" . 'font-lock-operator)     ;; '=' is an operator
    ("," . 'font-lock-builtin)     ;; ';' is a built-in
    (";" . 'font-lock-builtin))     ;; ';' is a built-in
  '("\\.myext$")                      ;; files for which to activate this mode
  '((lambda () (modify-syntax-entry ?' "\""))) ;; other functions to call
  "A generic mode for myext files"            ;; doc string for this mode
  )
```